# How to change permission when pushing an action?

Tags: permissions

Hello I successfully deployed my contract on the jungle testnet on the account rpstestacc13. However when I want to push an action it says that it is missing authority of rpstestacc13.

```
polo@polo-Ubuntu:~/contracts/rps$ cleos -u https://jungle2.eosio.cr:443 push action rpstestacc13 choice '["rpstestacc13", "rock"]' -p rpstestacc13@active
Error 3090003: Provided keys, permissions, and delays do not satisfy declared authorizations
Ensure that you have the related private keys inside your wallet and your wallet is unlocked.
Error Details:
transaction declares authority '{"actor":"rpstestacc13","permission":"active"}', but does not have signatures for it under a provided delay of 0 ms, provided permissions [{"actor":"rpstestacc13","permission":"eosio.code"}], provided keys [], and a delay max limit of 3888000000 ms
pending console output:
```

This is this command I wrote:

```
cleos -u https://jungle2.eosio.cr:443 push action rpstestacc13 choice '["rpstestacc13", "rock"]' -p rpstestacc13@active`
```

Answer (score 1):

Some actions need `eosio.code` permission to execute. Try setting `eosio.code` permission on your contract. 
To set permission, use

```
cleos -u https://jungle2.eosio.cr:443 set account permission --add-code rpstestacc13 active
```

OR

```
cleos -u https://jungle2.eosio.cr:443 set account permission rpstestacc13 active '{"threshold":1, "keys":[{"key":"YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY", "weight":1 }],"accounts":[{ "permission":{"actor":"rpstestacc13","permission":"eosio.code"},"weight":1}]}'
-p rpstestacc13@owner
```

For `eosio.code` details you can refer to this [answer](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/3841/what-is-eosio-code-permission)

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm that you have and rpctestacc123 account if the account is there make sure to import private_key of that account into your wallet using this

```
cleos wallet import private_keys -n wallet_name
```